# Wavy video export in Premiere Pro

Tags: premiere

I've exported a video within Premiere Pro & certain areas of the video produce wavy lines or it comes out distorted. What could be the cause of this and how can this be fixed?

See below for an example.

**Exported Video:** [image]
[image]

**Same clip within Premiere Pro:**

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are interlacing problems it looks like. In the editor, it displays 'deinterlaced' previews so you won't notice this in the editor. In the clip, select "Field options" and then "Always deinterlace" then render your video again, it should be fine then.